Losing files and changes once doing rebase with GIT
My branch is way too behind the main development branch and I want to add these changes to my feature branch
I have rebased my feature branch to main development and I can only see other team changes, I can not see my changes, what I have done is a big change includes adding new files, how to do this with Git GUI , Is merging a better choice in this case
The goal is to rebase my work on development that mean rewrite the history to be based on development, so merge request can be easier with no conflicts
SOLVED: It seems that I have to do git rebase --continue in each step and resolve the conflicts and added them and after that I have to also do git rebase --continue again
git rebase --skip to have the process faster and to clean the history
Conflicts solved manually, added and committed them and then continue rebase, until last commit reached, and rebase was successful.
After successful rebase I have pushed into new feature branch and ask for merge to main development and there was no conflicts in merge request

Did you commit your changes? Did you stash them? Also, do you mean Git GUI (not DUI)?

it seems that I have to do git rebase --continue
in each step and resolve the conflicts and added them and after that I have to also do git rebase --continue again

Are you still in the middle of a rebase?

If you rebase and you get merge conflicts, you can get them on every intermediate commit, so you may have to get through many, many merge conflicts in order to finish the rebase successfully. But if you merge and you get merge conflicts, you only have to deal with them once.

Thank you for your comment, it was really helpful I did rebase and I have did git rebase --skip
in some of commits that I don't need and to clear the history

In my opinion merge is better :

Even if it look "ugly" at first, you will still be able to see the history of your work. And that is great because you will still be able to "see" the merging state. But I understand this choice : it's simpler.
Rebase is not managable in many case : you can't push a rebase on a distant repo without creating problems to your co-worker. See this
Also your changes will still exist in the new merge commit, wich apparently does'nt happened in your case.

You can also try to test the 2 options WITHOUT PUSHING ! So you can see what's feel better.

thank you for your comment, the goal is to rebase my work on development that mean rewrite the history to be based on development, so merge request can be easier with no conflicts , after successful rebase I have pushed into new feature branch and ask for merge to main development and there was no conflicts in merge request

Rebase is a fine way to work which doesn’t lose work if used correctly.
